# How to export blender object with negative spaces to a print ready STL/OBJ file

Tags: modeling, workflow, 3d-printing

I'm just learning the basics in blender and wanted to create things I could use to sped up the learning process so I made a custom base for Warhammer AOS chaos figures.
The method I've used is mashing objects with some being negative spaces (ctrl+-) in relation between two or more objects.

Blender preview is like this:[image]

but previews in different viewers (windows, online) are like this:
[image]

So I'm a bit lost at how to export the file with negative/invisible objects being, well, negative and invisible as I want to print this on a 3D or resin printer, thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do but here's a good video that might help
https://youtu.be/-OynHqYd_1I  and https://youtu.be/iUUnMJtw_Qc

Comment: Yeah that would do. My whole approach was incorrect as it is better to add and manipulate vertexes instead of throwing a lot of new objects hoping for the best.